# Is it normal to be able to see https headers?

Tags: delphi, ssl, https, indy

I've written a small application using delphi to update my twitter status.
I use Indy 10 and OpenSSL and everything works fine, which means that i can both authenticate my app and update my status.

The thing is that if i use a program like "http analyzer" i can see the request's headers and so i can see sensitive information like the consumer_key.

Is that normal or is it a sign that i have not set properly the iohandler (TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL)?

```
mSslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
mSslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmBoth;
mSslIoHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
mSslIoHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
```

Comment: Definitely not normal if you are expecting to use an SSL connection. Are you connecting to an HTTPS url? Oh and, why are you limiting your choice to the SSLv3 protocol, as OpenSSL supports TLS 1.0 (1.1 and 1.2 depending on the version)?

Comment: @RemiGacogne yes i do connect to a https url. no special reason for the SSLv3, still in testing mode so i will move to TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By providing their own SSL certificates, HTTP analyzers are able to monitor the HTTP traffic as if it was unencrypted. I guess you have to set the analyzer IP address and port as proxy only, and leave the destination server address and port unchanged in the client. Then the analyzer will be able to decrypt your client data with its own key, and forwards it to the destination server. (This is the same way a 'man in the middle'-attack would work)

So yes, it is normall with this type of HTTP analyzers (such as Fiddler)

Comment: For MITM analyzers, like Fiddler, this is true.  Packet sniffers, like Wireshark, would not be able to decrypt the HTTPS data unless configured with the server's private key (see http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).